# formatting textboxes in cakephp (make textbox bigger)

Tags: cakephp, textbox, formatting

hi all, I'm trying to style the text boxes in my cakephp form but am having no luck. I am trying to make them bigger in relative size but am unsure on how to approach this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<table align=center>
  <?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')));?>
  <tr>          
    <td align=center>Username: </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ><?php echo $this->Form->input('username',array('label'=>false,'size'=>100));?></td>
  </tr>     
  <tr>      
    <td align = center>Password: </td>
  </tr>         
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('password',array('label'=>false,'size'=>100));?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align=center><?php echo $this->Form->end('Login');?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the default cakePHP CSS template? If so then change the width of the input in the main CSS file (cake.generic.css).

style="width: 300px;"

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it stands will create invalid markup - you should fix that before you worry about how it looks :-)

Also, tables for layout? In this day and age? Anyway...

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login')));?>
<table align=center>
  <tr>          
    <td align=center>Username: </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td ><?php echo $this->Form->input('username',array('label'=>false,'size'=>100));?></td>
  </tr>     
  <tr>      
    <td align = center>Password: </td>
  </tr>         
    <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('password',array('label'=>false,'size'=>100));?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align=center><?php echo $this->Form->submit('Login');?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

(I've moved the  elements outside of the table - they were invalid in your posted code)

css:

form div.input input {
    width: 200px;
}

You will be doing yourself a huge favour if you ditch tables all together and your code will be simpler:

```
<?php

echo $this->Form->create('User');

echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
    'User.username',
    'User.password'
));

echo $this->Form->submit('Login');

echo $this->Form->end();

?>
```

css:

```
form {
    overflow: hidden;
}
form div.input {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}
form div.input label {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 10em;
}

form div.input input {
    width: 200px;
}
```